# JQuery-UI autocomplete. Automatically accept the word when only one choice is left

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a web form with an text input field that has autocomplete widget attached to it via-jquery-ui.  In fact the form itself is jquery-ui dialog.  I am looking for the way to make the form automatically accept the auto-complete choice when there is only one option left.

To illustrate.  Say user enter 'c'  the autocomplete widget proposes 'cat' and 'closet'. When user enters 'a' the widget should automatically put 'cat' into the input field and close itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage an event.
As I see in [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) you have to trigger change:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  change: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

in change you have the count the options you still have like this:

```
var options = $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option" );
```

As i see you'll get something like that:

```
[{label: 'Option 1'}, {label: 'Option 2'}]
```

Play a bit with split and eval and get the size.
Then:

```
if (size == 1){
 $(".selector").val(options.value);
}
```

It's not a working sample of course but it's the method.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work.  The "change" event is triggered only when the autocomplete widget is blurred.  I actually need it to trigger while user is typing.

Comment: All right, do the same but go for a custom "onclick" event (and function). <input class="selector" onclick="myAutocompleteHandleKeyPress(event)"> and in this new function get $('.selector').val() and so on.